# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not determine a type for class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataTable

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, datatable

```
SQLServerDataTable referenceFilterDT = new TransferDataUtil().generateDataTable(referenceFilters);

if(null != referenceFilterDT) {
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createNativeQuery("exec p_GetQuestionWiseResponseMetrics_Samik :referenceFilterDT");
    query.setParameter("referenceFilterDT", referenceFilterDT);
    List<?> status = query.getResultList();
}
```

I'm trying to pass a datatable type to a SQL Server stored procedure, but
hibernate is throwing exception:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not determine a type for class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataTable